# Não consigo instalar o Zeos no Delphi 7

Tags: delphi-7

Baixei a versão mais recente do Zeos, compilo todos os arquivos, mas na hora de instalar ele fala que o arquivo C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Project\Bpl\ZComponentDesign70.bpl não existe, mas ele está lá. Já tentei com diversas formas que achei mas em todas isto ocorre. Já alterei a Library e não adiantou. Um dos links fala das DLLs que preciso para acessar o MySQL, que tem uma pasta lib no arquivo RAR, mas nenhum que encontrei tem esta pasta, pode ser isto? Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Vá ao menu:

Tools > Enviroment Options > Library > Library path

Clique nos ... (3 pontos)

Vai abrir a tela Directories

Clique em ... (3 pontos)

Adicione o local aonde está o arquivo.

Comment: Obrigado, tudo certo